# Confusion in datafetching from oodle API

Tags: asp.net, xml

I am currently editing my previous question because I finally found the solution "how to manage with oodle API ?" Now the actual point is I dont know how to integrate the result !

let me give you example I have generated my API key and through my API key I can access data from oodle !

http://api.oodle.com/api/v2/listings?key=TEST&region=chicago&category=vehicle/car

In case of "TEST" i write my API key.

Now the problem is this link returns value in XML but how can i fetch it from XML ? Now the point is I don't want to open this link but I want XML data from the page ! Try to visit link given above. You can get idea.

Hope for the positive answer !

For more information I have read this link
http://developer.oodle.com/

Comment: I have gone through some stuffs and I got it. If anyone has problem, comment here I would help him